# change color brightness in android

Tags: android, brightness

I want to change brightness in color

I implemented this...

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 200);
```

this will change my device's brightness in black&white mode.

[image][image]

like above images, I can change brightness but how can I give color?
Is there any other parameter which I don't know?

Comment: current images taken form any other app or your mock Ui?

Comment: I think `Service` is used for that, which keeps color screen on device.If `service` is stopped then nothing. but I did not find any clue that how to implement this coloring.

Comment: Any Idea for that i have to do like that 
Give me some clue.  how to change screen brightness color
@BhaveshHirpara

Answer (score 5):

This can be accomplished using windows of type TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT. 
The idea is that even services can have a Window; so you can use a service, which makes a view  and call WindowManager#addView() with a view and layout params. In your case, the view will just have a background color with an alpha value. You can experiment with different layout params to achieve the required effect.

This is also how facebook chat heads works. Check out this link to know more about the implementation details: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/ This will give you an idea on how to go about implementing this type of screen overlay.

Comment: The page on the mentioned link ( http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/ ) does not exist.

Comment: but we have waybackmachine: http://web.archive.org/web/20160205160752/http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/