# "DRAW OVER OTHER APP" is which permission in android

Tags: android, permissions

**DRAW OVER OTHER APPS**

Allows the app to draw on top of other applications or parts of the user interface. They may interfere with your use of the interface in any application, or change what you think you are seeing in other applications.

which permission or receiver is associated with above text.

**here is image**

[image]

Comment: Please post the link to where you got this text

Comment: in play https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netmanslab.sa

Comment: You can open the apk and check the manifest for it. It is a normal zip file, and you can get it with most app managers

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is probably

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

This would make sense as system alert windows do draw on top of everything.

Comment: actually I want to do this, see my quesyion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127264/change-color-brightness-in-android

Comment: You can see this in the source here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I have no idea, I haven't actually coded something like this. I'm guessing since it is a system level alert, it can be transparent touch wise (pass off touch events to whatever it is over).