# Broadcast receiver popup message in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application i using a broadcastreceiver to receive a incoming call and shown a some details to user.  It works fine, but when i opened the application and incoming call is received, it shows at top of application, not the top of incoming call screen. How to solve this issue ?

thanks in advance

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
      public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {                                         // 1
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);                         // 2
            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {                                   // 3
                String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);  // 4
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, Test1.class); 
                        i.putExtras(intent);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        context.startActivity(i);
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
```

**Message Showing Activity**

```
    public class Test1 extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.popup);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        wmlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
        String number = getIntent().getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setText(number);

        TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv2.setText(MyApp.mDbh.check(number));

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                finish();                    
            }                   
        }, 10 *1000);
    }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14129720/435706

Comment: @Shereef I also want to control call button in calling screen.  Is it possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1