# Show Textbox out of app using OpenGL

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es

I'm trying to implement something similar to Facebook Chat Heads.
I'm using Android Studio to build an Android Application with the OpenGL library.

OpenGL is neccessary because I need full controll about the timing of a visual component I want to display.
I'm just not sure if there is a possibility to show something similar like a TextView outside of my app? I.e., to overlay other apps in a similar manner to the Facebook Chat Heads?

What would be the right way to implement a textbox which could be displayed out of the app, like on home screen, using OpenGL?
Would be much appreciated if someone could give me a hint, because I did'nt find a way to make the overlay visible while being controlled from within my application.

Disclaimer: I already tried this using a `TextView` and a `Handler` with `postDelayed()`, but I couldn't control the timings as exact as I need them to be.

Comment: You could look at the following links: http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.ru/2013/05/facebook-chat-heads-feature.html?m=1; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129595/draw-over-other-app-is-which-permission-in-android; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264650/how-to-draw-a-view-on-top-of-everything; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads.

Comment: Yes, I already tryed this and it worked finde for me. It's a performance problem. Next requirement was to display the text for 30 ms, which wasn't feasable using a TextView. Therefore I'm trying 'OpenGL' to get full control over perfomance and display time.