# when i clicked messenger how applock coming over my messenger screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I locked my apps using app lock and when i clicked the locked apps,How does the app lock authentication screen comes in foreground of my locked app screen and after authenticate succeeded it closes automatically?

Comment: Please try to add more detail in question.

Comment: I am creating an fingerprint app lock application,i need to know about draw over other apps.so suggest me reference.Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

> You should go for **Draw Over Other Apps**

check these answers

["DRAW OVER OTHER APP" is which permission in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129595/draw-over-other-app-is-which-permission-in-android)

[How to draw a view on top of everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264650/how-to-draw-a-view-on-top-of-everything)

[What APIs in Android is Facebook using to create Chat Heads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)

> **[Example for the same](https://codingshark.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/how-to-draw-on-top-of-other-applications/)**